# Concept of reversing a string using recursive function

Tags: c, pointers, recursion

```
void foo3(char *x) 
{
  if (!*x) return;
  foo3(x+1);
  printf("%c ",*x);
}
```

If for example `x` points to an array `ar[]="abc"`, why does it print `"cba"`? Why does it even print if it will just keep re-entering the function over and over until the if is true then it returns.

How does it print?

Comment: Note: the posted code does not print `cba`  Rather, it prints: `c b a `

Answer (score 5):

If you call `foo3("hi")`, the first thing it does is look at the 'h' pointed to by the parameter `x`. Since that is non-zero, it calls `foo3("i")`--meaning that it passes the address of the *rest of the string*.

`foo3("i")` looks at the 'i', sees it's non-zero, and calls `foo3("")` -- technically it passes the address of the null terminator to the original string.

`foo3("")` looks at the null terminator, and returns.

`foo3("i")` prints the 'i' and returns.

`foo3("hi")` prints the 'h'.

The function works because it makes the recursive call *before* printing the "current character", so that the rest of the string will be printed before it.

Answer (score 2):

The call stack would look like this (pseudo-code) which should show how and why it prints 'cba'.

x is a C-style array 'a', 'b', 'c', '\0'

```
call foo3(x)
    call foo3(x+1)
        call foo3(x+2)
            call foo3(x+3)
            return to foo3(x+2)
        print(x+2) 'c'
        return to foo3(x+1)
    print(x+1) 'b'
    return to foo3(x)
print(x) 'a'
return to calling program
```

Answer (score 0):

We can extract a general *rule of thumb* from this:  If you process some data and then recur, you're working on the data from front to back; if you recur then process some data, you're working on the data from back to front.  You can see this if you reverse the last two lines:

```
void foo3(char *x) 
{
    if (!*x) return;
    printf("%c ", *x);
    foo3(x + 1);
}
```

The data comes out in the original order as we're now processing some data and then recurring.

Answer (score 0):

@cdlane has a point. This example with two printf will help you understand the mechanism behind recusrion.

```
#include <stdio.h>
void foo3(char *x)
{
    printf("%c=\n",*x);
    if (*x=='\0') return;
    foo3(x+1);
    printf("%c ",*x);
}
int main(void)
{
    foo3("abc");
    return 0;
}
```